# Launch different activities depending on spinner selection

Tags: android, button, android-activity, spinner

I've got and activity with two spinners and a button. The values of the second spinner change depending on the item selected in the first one.

Now, what I want to do is to launch an activity or another depending on the selection in the second spinner after pressing an "OK" button.

Here is the code of the main activity:

```
public class UniversityActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner s1, s2;
Button acceptbutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.university_layout);
    addListenerOnButton();

    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;

    acceptbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept);
    acceptbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DegreeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Universidad Politécnica de Madrid")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Grado en Ingeniería Aeronáutica");
        list.add("Grado en Ingeniería Geológica");
        list.add("Grado en Ingeniería Informática");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Universidad Autónoma de Madrid")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Grado en Historia");
        list.add("Grado en Ingeniería Química");
        list.add("Grado en Ingeniería en Tecnologías Industriales");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
              dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And this is its layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Select university -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/selectuniv"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow" />

<!-- Spinner 1 Dropdown -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:entries="@array/univ" />

<!-- Select degree -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:text="@string/selectdeg"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow" />

<!-- Spinner 2 Dropdown -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<!-- Accept button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/accept"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/accept"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton2" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: get the selected text from spinner and check when you click on accept button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime the values of your second spinner changes, save it in a global string variable by declaring a string at the top of your file. Like this:

```
public class UniversityActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner s1, s2;
Button acceptbutton;
String _globalString 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

............................................................
```

Now you need to save the value of your selected field into that string, everytime your spinner changes value.

```
loginSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            _globalString = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Then you have access over the last selected value of your second spinner. Then everytime the button is pressed, you check with what value does my _globalString match?

```
 acceptbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
if(_globalString == "activity1")
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}

if(_globalString == "activity2")
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}

            }
        });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to get Selected text from Spinner and use **switch** or **if-else**. Use `getSelectedItem().toString()`
**For example:**

```
String textFromSpinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(textFromSpinner.equals("TEXT1")){
Intent intent = new Intent(Acivity.this, NextAcivitiy.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
else if(textFromSpinner.equals("TEXT2")){
//start another
}
else if(...){
//similarly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to use `setOnItemSelectedListener`

```
loginSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

by String

```
  String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
   if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("compareString"))
            {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ONEActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
      }else{

     Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,TWOActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
      }
```

by Position

```
            if(position == 1)
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ONEActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
       Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,TWOActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
     }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String chosenValue = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

if(chosenValue.equals("Grado en Historia"){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else if...
```

You can compare with the different values

Answer (score 0):

Just get the text from spinner as:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Check condition in on click accept button like:

```
acceptbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

if(text.equals("selectedItem")){
    // do some thing
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DegreeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
    // do some thing
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

         overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a private method which creates an appropriate intent, depending on the spinner selection.

replace :

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, DegreeActivity.class);`

with

`Intent intent = createActivityIntent(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());`

`private Intent createActivityIntent(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 1 : return new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        case 2 : return new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
        default : return new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    }`